# NSData.decompressed throws error in Swift

Tags: swift, compression, gzip, nsdata

Hei folks, i want to decompress a gz file using NSData's decompressed method in Swift.
The file is loaded successfully into NSData, but if i try to decompress it, it trows error.

```
var data: NSData
let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
var url = paths[0]
    
url.appendPathComponent("g.srt.gz")

do {
    data = try Data(contentsOf: url) as NSData
    print(data)
    let dec = try data.decompressed(using: .zlib)
        
} catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }
```

Here is the output i see:

```
{length = 17859, bytes = 0x1f8b0800 00000000 00038d7d cd8ee446 ... 10deea38 94b70000 }
The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 5377.)
```

I tried all DecompressionAlgorithms, and i get always the error above. In the Finder i am able to decompress it, so it's not damaged.

Am i missing something (Capability or eomething else in Info.plist) ? I dont want to use any external lib or framework.

My environment is macOS 11.3.1, Xcode 12.5, Swift 5

Comment: `print(error)` not `print(error.localizedDescription)` it might give more infos. Also what third party lib are you using? Not https://github.com/1024jp/GzipSwift ?

Comment: @Larme Unfortunately not.  `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=5377 "(null)"`
I looked for the error code, it means `NSDecompressionFailedError `

Comment: @Larme It's Apples dedicated API for compressing or decompressing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That data is a gzip stream, not a zlib stream. The method you are using [does not have an option for gzip](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/compressionalgorithm). See [this](https://github.com/1024jp/NSData-GZIP) for a solution.

Comment: "this answer" is now a dead link.

Comment: Not completely dead. Only _mostly_ dead.

Comment: Sufficiently dead that I have no idea what the promised "... for a **solution**" there might be.  I'm also getting the 5377 error, trying each of the alternatives to .zlib yields the same error, and this page is at the top of the Google search when trying to get info on the error.  If there is an answer to decompressing a .gz file with native Swift tools, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest questions can be the hardest to find answers to... should one ***expect*** that `let dec = try data.decompressed(using: .zlib)` can ever be made to decompress a .gz file, or (in 2022) is it necessary to go to an external library in order to do that?

Comment: That's weird. I edited the link, but it didn't stick. Anyway, mostly dead means that with sufficient reputation, you can still see deleted answers here. I copied the link in that deleted answer to this answer.

Comment: An already built-in external library, yes. The zlib library installed in macOS can decode gzip files. It is only the Swift interface to that library that lacks that capability.

Comment: AH!  Yeah, I don't have the rep to see those.  And so I guess Swift for iOS needs to use the solution from GitHub in any event.  Thanks for clearing that up; back to productive programming, leaving the head/bricks interface behind for a while. Cheers!